# how to sticky navbar and right side on Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

I saw this [page from upwork](https://www.upwork.com/services/product/an-secure-stripe-payment-gateway-integration-on-your-website-1315524826073997312?utm_campaign=SEM_GGL_INTL_NonBrand_CATALOG_DSA&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=121161479933&utm_term&campaignid=11764071036&matchtype=b&device=c&partnerId=Cj0KCQjwnoqLBhD4ARIsAL5JedIlWaZ-BAVRN3IyaYX2wq5LuRi4twTPShEtB3JLSZsZydFq36aJNPoaAjgOEALw_wcB%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle) 
I want to know how to create CSS or javascript to sticky navbar and right side like that page.

I can sticky navbar for now, but still cannot sticky right side. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt

Comment: you may find this helpful https://dev.to/clairecodes/how-to-make-a-sticky-sidebar-with-two-lines-of-css-2ki7